# Return Bool from Mongoose virtual

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

In MEAN stack project, I want to find if there are likes for a comment or not. "Comment" is the acutal comment schema and "CommentReaction" schema stores details of users who liked the comment. Using below code, I'm able to get the count of number of likes for a comment. In my Angular code, I'm checking if count is more than 0 or not and its working good.

```
commentSchema.virtual('likes', {
  ref: 'CommentReaction',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'commentId',
  count: true
});
```

But I am expecting the REST API to return true or false accordingly. How can I modify my above code to return true or false only?

Answer (score 2):

You could define another `virtual` and check the `count` for `members` there:

```
commentSchema.virtual('hasLikes', {
    foreignField: 'likes', // must match the previous virtual
}).get(function () {
    return this.likes > 0;
});
```

Make sure to enable the `virtual` options for `toJSON/toObject`:

```
commentSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
commentSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```

and finally correctly populate the query:

```
const res = await Comment.find({}).populate('likes').populate('hasLikes').exec();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `this` doesn't exist inside an arrow function btw, just replace `() => {}` with `function() {}` in the `.get` part in the first block

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa: Oh, you are right. Fixed it, thanks :)